# How can I assert array with object in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, testing

I want to assert array fake data with object. I use `assertEquals()` but it is not working. How can I assert the properties?

```
$fakeData = [
    'id'         => 1,
    'first_name' => fake()->firstName,
    'last_name'  => fake()->lastName,
    'city'       => fake()->city,
];

$myquery = DB::table('users')
    ->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city')
    ->where('id', '=', 1)
    ->get();

$this->assertEquals($fakeData, $myquery);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Laravel's` DB in the way you are using it, returns an collection. Firstly get it to return an object instead. Therefor your fake data should also be an object, `PHP` can easily convert arrays to objects and vice versa with casting `(array)` or `(object)`.

```
$fakeData = (object)[ 
    'id'         => 1,
    'first_name' => fake()->firstName,
    'last_name'  => fake()->lastName,
    'city'       => fake()->city,
];

$myRow = DB::table('users')
       ->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city')
       ->where('id', '=', 1)
       ->first();

$this->assertEquals($fakeData, $myRow);
```

In more practical terms, most of the times it is easier to assert what is in the database, using `assertDatabaseHas()` instead.

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas(
    'users', 
    [
        'id'         => 1,
        'first_name' => 'some_first_name',
        'last_name'  => 'some_last_name',
        'city'       => 'some_city',
    ],
);
```